# Entity Framework db first: states machine associations

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, datatable

I want to manage a simple state machine with EF.
I have a registry table of states and I'm supposed to have a table with two fields: an ID of a starting state and an ID of a destination state.
The associations table should have distinct couples of starting and destination ids.
I tried to make both of field as primary key and as foreign key referring to the registry table, but it's bad imported into the edmx model.

The registry state is like this:

```
ID    DESCR
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

the associations table should be like this:

```
ID_STATE_START    ID_STATE_DEST
1                 2
2                 3
```

So, in this case I can say that a process can go from A to B and from B to C.

EDIT:
This is the model VS2017 created for me:

[image]

I have two tables in db, but VS imported just the registry with two references on its own.
By the way this is not importan since i just need a right solution.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you mean by _it's bad imported into the edmx model_ can you paste your model code in your question and what you expect it to be?

Comment: @PriyankPanchal i added the model, but it's not importan what VS made because i need a correct solution for my problem.

Comment: I think this is because EF will not import a "junction" table in case of many-to-many relationship. And in your case as we can see it is a self-referencing many-to-many relationship. I am not 100% sure as for your case though.